# What is the difference of using ... operator to add list to another list?

Tags: flutter, dart

I usually use this method to add list into another list

```
  List newData = data;
```

But one of my developer friend use this `...` operator to add list into another list like this, what is the difference between this both method ? I try to search for the answer but cannot understand.

```
  List data = [
    {
      'value': 'value one',
    },
    {
      'value': 'value two',
    },
  ];

  List newData = [...data];
```

Comment: `List newData = data;` makes `newData` refer to the same object that `data` refers to. `List newData = [...data];` creates a new `List` object with the contents of `data` (i.e., it creates a shallow copy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List newData = data` this will create a new reference to the same object.
Let's assume that `List data = ['a', 'b', 'c'];`
so if you called
newData[0] = 'x';

```
//Lets assume the following
List data = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
List newData = data;
data[0] = 'x';
print(data);
print(newData);

//this code will print the same data for both lists, you will find in the console:
['x', 'b', 'c']
['x', 'b', 'c']
//changing the first value in the data List effected both lists
```

but if you created a `newData = [...data];` this will create a new list and copy the data from `data` to `newData`

```
//Lets assume the following
List data = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
List newData = [...data];
data[0] = 'x';
print(data);
print(newData);

//this code will print the same data for both lists, you will find in the console:
['x', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c']
//changing the first value in the data List effected only the data list
```

usually making a new pointer to the same reference is not what's intended
but using the second method will take more space from the memory

---

**UPDATE:**

- when to use the first method and when to use the second
  if you want to update your list, remove, replace or add elements without saving the old data, then you can use the first method, but personally, I don't see that you need to create a `newData` list because you can do what you want directly to your `data` list
- If you want to update your list **but saving your old data** to refer to it in the future, then you must use the second method, because playing with `newData` list does not effect the original list in that case

Comment: okay thank you, i'll try it to understand it more

Comment: one more, so what is better to use  is it newData = data or newData =[...data] ?

Comment: it depends, do you want to change your data? if yes then the first way.  
if you want to preserve your original data, then you have clone your list, play with the copiedList and then you have both lists, the original and the updated, to achieve that, use the second way

Comment: I updated my answer to describe a little bit the difference and use cases